# gdb ставит bp не туда, куда я прошу

Tags: linux, c, gdb

```
    GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.7.1-0ubuntu5~14.04.2) 7.7.1
(gdb) b 6
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4006a5: file binbit.c, line 6.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/alexander/Рабочий стол/c5ex/ch15/my/binbit 
Breakpoint 1, main () at binbit.c:7
warning: Source file is more recent than executable.
7   {

console:
-rwxrwxr-x 1 alexander alexander 10345 июля 9 15:55 binbit*
-rw-rw-r-- 1 alexander alexander 1880 июля 11 18:47 binbit.c
-rw-rw-r-- 1 alexander alexander 1891 июля 11 18:29 binbit.c~
```

Comment: А куда Вы просите поставить точку останова ?

Comment: так я написал же: (gdb) b 6
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4006a5: file binbit.c, line 6. А он подлец  Breakpoint 1, main () at binbit.c:7  и так все время

Comment: а на 6 line есть исходный код ? и если есть при компиляции используете -O ?

Comment: строка 6 int main(void) а 7 {   (скобка). Компилирую так gcc -g -std=c99 binbit.c -o binbit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это стандартное поведение gdb . при указании точки останова на функции, отладчик останавливается на первой строчки внутри функции.

Comment: @dio4 Как бы не плохо было бы, чтобы Ваше `спасибо` забулькало и упало в карман ответившему.  Если настолько лень уж прочитать правила пользования сайтом, то подскажу, что в Вашем случае `спасибо` можно отметить галочкой внизу под цифрой (слева от ответа). А в целом, когда пишите ответ на комментарий кому-либо, то он его не увидит, пока Вы не прочитаете справку (ссылка справа от окна ввода комментария) и не оформите свой комментарий должным образом.